# OpenCV image in OpenGL: Strange behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, texture-mapping, iplimage

I'm using the following code to create and display a texture from an IplImage. It works about half the time but sometimes skews the image, I assume it has to do with the texture padding but I need help with a fix.

```
int loadTexture_Ipl(IplImage *image, GLuint *text) {
    if (image==NULL) return -1;
    glGenTextures(1, text);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, *text );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->width, image->height,0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
    return 0;
}
```

This link is a screenshot of the output incase anyone has delt with a similar problem.

[image: Skew problem]

Comment: how about the `glBegin/End()` routine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here is the fact that one row of your `IplImage` in memory might be wider than the actual used image (this is due to performance reasons). You're on the right track using `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` - just with the wrong value.

As a simple example, imagine an image being 3 pixels wide. So one row (RGB) essentially consists of 9 bytes (byte alignment; no spacing between rows), 10 bytes (even byte alignment; 1 byte space between rows), 12 bytes (word alignment; 3 bytes space between rows) or 16 bytes (double word alignment; 7 bytes space between rows).

Can't look it up right now, but I think the rows of an IplImage are aligned at word boundaries by default. Due to you using RGB (with 3 bytes per pixel; not 4 bytes) this is an issue. Just try different values, I think you'll need word alignment (`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);`).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks a bunch for the speedy response!